# Swift - HLS CUE Metadata Capture

Tags: swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, tvos, m3u8

Working with HLS and therefore m3u8 files that contain ongoing metadata during the stream. I need to intercept metadata such as `#EXT-X-CUE-OUT` and `#EXT-X-CUE-IN`. I am not finding a process with `AVPlayer` that reports on these kinds of tags within the stream. Is there a means of capturing this sort of metadata during the streaming of the content? I know there are things like `AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector`, however, that does not seem to address the tags I am talking about.